# Jenkins scripted Pipeline - Parallel - call function multiple times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to call a function multiple times, in parallel, but don't really know how many times it will be called, it will depend on the values on a list.
Code example:

```
def buildJob(jobName) {
    echo "${jobName} will be built." //testing output before really building jobs
}

node {
    projects = ['project1-dev', 'project2-dev', 'project1-qa', 'project2-qa', 'project1-pp', 'project2-pp']

    stage ('Build') {
        for (project in projects) {
            parallel(
                "${project}": buildJob(project), failFast: true
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I want the code to generate something like this:

```
stage ('Build') {
    parallel (
        'project1-dev': { buildJob('project1-dev') },
        'project1-qa': { buildJob('project1-qa') },
        'project1-pp': { buildJob('project1-pp') },
        ...
    )
}
```

But I'm really not understanding how to pass the parameter buildJob(project), I've tried many different ways, sometimes I get failFast error, sometimes project name error, sometimes the map is not fully recognized.
I even made a map and added values dynamically to it, but I thought I was over-complicating this, I just want to call the function multiple times and don't wait for the result, except wait for every single call to be completed.

Can anybody help, please?
Thanks a lot!
Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of battling, I solved it like this:

```
def buildJob(jobName){
    echo "${jobName} will be built."
}

node {

    map = [:]
    projects = ['project1-dev', 'project2-dev', 'project1-qa', 'project2-qa', 'project1-pp', 'project2-pp']

    stage ('Build') {
        for (project in projects) {
            map[project] = { buildJob("'${project}'") }
        }

        parallel map
    } 
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to make failFast work with this?

Comment: At the time I just used it to create the loop, the failFast part was just something that occurred, that I wanted to avoid. So I haven't used it after that.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using `each` instead of `for`:

```
def buildJob(jobName){
    echo "${jobName} will be built."
}

node {

    map = [:]
    projects = ['project1-dev', 'project2-dev', 'project1-qa', 'project2-qa', 'project1-pp', 'project2-pp']

    stage ('Build') {
        projects.each() {
            map[it] = { buildJob(it) }
        }

        parallel map
    } 
}
```